# Prove magnitude of zeros of polynomial $\le\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Let $(a_0,a_2\dots,a_{n-1})\in[0,1]^n$, and $k\in\Bbb C$ be a zero of $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. Prove that $|k|\le\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$.

Firstly, $\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$ seems to come from quadratics such as $x^2-x-1=0$. So I tried the triangle inequality to obtain a quadratic inequality about $|k|$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i|k|^i\ge\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a_ik^i\right|=\left|k^n+a_{n-1}k^{n-1}\right|=|k|^{n-1}|k+a_{n-1}|.$$
I'm not sure whether this is the right way...

Comment: The claim is wrong. Consider $$f(x)=x^2+1=0.$$ Its roots are $\pm i$ and $\lvert \pm i\rvert \not \leq \frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2}$.

Comment: Looking at your example, did you want $ a_i \in \{ -1, 1 \}$?

Comment: Edit: should be $\require{cancel}\frac{\sqrt5\cancel-+1}2$.

Comment: The solution of the problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4424740) (prior to "update" section).

Comment: @user Thank you for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

For the real case you have in term of Continued fraction a solution here . [Got a factored version of the Taylor's series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738155/got-a-factored-version-of-the-taylors-series/4774119#4774119)

Some details :

### The even case :

Let $a_i>0$ then define :

$$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^{2i}=0$$

Or squaring:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^{2i})^2=(a_0)^2$$

Now it preserves one roots which have a pure imaginary part (need an argument I don't know such).

Or :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}x^{4k}+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}x^{i+j}=a_{0}^{2}\tag{J}$$

Now we translate this polynomial into :

$$x\left(b_0(1+x)+\frac{b_1}{x+1}+\frac{b_2}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}+\cdots+\frac{b_{n}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots x}}}}\right)-C=0$$

Or squaring and $x\to x^2$:

$$Q(x)=x^2\left(b_{0}\left(x^2+1\right)+b_{1}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}+b_{2}\frac{x^2+1}{x+2}+b_{3}\cdot\frac{x^2+2}{2x^2+3}+\cdot\cdot+\frac{b_{n}\left(F_{n-2}x^2+F_{n-1}\right)}{F_{n-1}x^2+F_{n}}\right)^2=C^2 \tag{J}$$

To have the Fibonacci's polynomials put all on one denominator and use

$$b_{k}=\left(-1\right)^{k}a_{k}^{2}+2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{j}a_{j}a_{2k-j}$$

Where :

$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^{i},q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_ix^{i}$$

Here $I,J$ .

Now setting $Q(mx),\exists m>1$ such that the coefficient decreases starting from the highest degree .

We have using $HM-GM$ ,$x_{root} \leq 1$

Example :

Let :

$$u(x+1)+\frac{y}{x+1}+\frac{z}{1+\frac{1}{1+x}}$$

Or :

$$\frac{ux^{3}+4ux^{2}+5ux+2u+x^{2}z+xy+2xz+2y+z}{x^{2}+3x+2}$$

Then using HM-GM we have the essential expression :

$$\left(u(x+1)\frac{y}{x+1}\frac{z}{1+\frac{1}{1+x}}\right)^{-1}$$

Iterating one time :

$$\left(zyu(xuyz+x+uyz+2)\left(uxyz+uyz+2x+4\right)^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$

And the conclusion follows from for $uyzx>1$

$$\frac{1}{9}\left(uyz(xuyz+x+uyz+2)\left(uxyz+uyz+2x+4\right)^{-1}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}<1$$

Which is obvious .

Comment: What do you mean? If $k$ real, then $k<0$, which is needless to say.

Comment: Hum I misread it for $(-1,1)$.I shall try to gives details .